# jQuery custom plugin undefined js function

Tags: jquery, plugins

Not sure what I'm doing incorrect.  I have a function inside my custom jQuery plugin, and my browsers are telling me it's undefined.

Can anyone see what I've done wrong inside:

```
(function($){

  $.fn.myCustomPlugin = function( ) {

    return this.each(function() {

        var theValue = $(this).text().trim().replace(/ /g,'');

        // STOP if theValue return nothing
        if (theValue === null || theValue === undefined || theValue == ""){ 
            $(this).html("nothing inside the span"); 
            return true; 
        }


        function clickActions()
        {
            alert("This alert shows when clicking on the element");     
            return false;
        }


        $(this).html('<a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="clickActions()">'+theValue+'</a>');

    }); // eof .each


  };
})(jQuery);
```

The Html is simple phone numbers inside spans:

```
<span class="formatme">123-8749674</span><br />
<span class="formatme">123-8749674</span><br />
<span class="formatme">123-8749674</span><br />
<span class="formatme">123-8749674</span><br />
<span class="formatme">123-8749674</span><br />

<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.formatme').myCustomPlugin();
});
</script>
```

the function clickActions() may be simply in the wrong place, but I've moved it around the plugin code, with the same results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use

```
$(this).text(theValue).on('click', function(e){
    alert("This alert shows when clicking on the element");     
    return false;
});
```

Also following line

```
var theValue = $(this).text().trim().replace(/ /g,'');
```

should be `$.trim()`

```
var theValue = $.trim($(this).text()).replace(/ /g,'');
```

[**Working Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/SZPY4/1/).

Comment: Thank you for adding the $.trim() comment.  That fixed the IE issue

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare you function thusly:

```
window.clickActions = function(){
    alert("This alert shows when clicking on the element");     
    return false;
}
```

...if it's to have global scoping as you currently are attempting to access it, in the `onclick` handler.

That said I'd suggest providing an object and scoping it within that object to prevent polluting the global namespace, as a matter of best practice.

Cheers

Comment: That seems to work in FF and Chrome.  IE appears to have issues.